# ¿Es obligatorio el uso del backbone y underscore en requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

soy nuevo en esto y recientemente estoy aprendiendo a utilizar requierejs y me gustaría saber si es necesario usar ***backbone*** y ***underscore*** , por que vi en varios en ejemplos que lo agregan al paths y de ser asi, también quisiera saber que es y para que se utiliza?

Este es uno de los ejemplos que encontre:

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'libs',
    paths : {
      backbone : 'backbone',
      underscore : 'underscore',
      jquery : 'jquery',
      marionette : 'backbone.marionette',
      wreqr : 'backbone.wreqr',
      eventbinder : 'backbone.eventbinder',
      babysitter : 'backbone.babysitter'
  } 
});
```

Comment: Podrias decirnos que es lo que encontraste en tus busquedas y que cosas no entiendes de eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no es obligatorio.

- [`RequireJS`](https://requirejs.org/) es un cargador de archivos y módulos `JavaScript` que implementa [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD).
- [`Backbone.js`](https://backbonejs.org/) es un **framework** (*o casi*) como `AngularJS`, `Vuejs`, etc. que utiliza `AMD` para la carga de sus componentes.
- [`Underscore.js`](https://underscorejs.org/) es un **toolkit**, como por ejemplo `jQuery`, `Lodash`, etc.